# Reusing Same JS Function and Object Repeatedly in Function

Tags: javascript, json, function

I'm building a JS function that calls another function.  I'm using the outer function to make it easier to pass required information in to the inner function.  Below is the current inner function:

```
someFunction("trackUnstructEvent", {
            schema: "iglu:com.example/" + some_event_name + "/jsonschema/1-0-0",
            data: {
                timeStamp: new Date()
            }
        },
        [{
            schema: "iglu:com.example/people/jsonschema/1-0-0",
            data: JSON.stringify(user)
        },
            {
                schema: "iglu:com.example/widgets/jsonschema/2-0-0",
                data: { JSON.stringify(widgets)
            }]
    )
```

This function is broken down into three parts:

Part A, which is always required:

```
someFunction("trackUnstructEvent", {
            schema: "iglu:com.example/" + some_event_name + "/jsonschema/1-0-0",
            data: {
                timeStamp: new Date()
            }
        },
```

Part B, which is optional:

```
[{
            schema: "iglu:com.example/people/jsonschema/1-0-0",
            data: JSON.stringify(user)
        },
```

and Part C, which is also optional:

```
{
                schema: "iglu:com.example/widgets/jsonschema/2-0-0",
                data: JSON.stringify(widgets)
            }]
    )
```

Currently, I am using if else statement to select which sections are being used in the inner function, but that just seems clunky.  I was hoping to get ideas for building a function that would use Part A without having it in the function multiple times, and also allow for dynamic insertion of parts B and C, depending on whether or not their respective parameters are populated in the outer function call.  BTW, the outer function call is simply this:

```
igluEvent(some_event_name, people, widgets){...}
```

So, if people is included, the some_event_name and people code is included, but not the widgets code.

Your ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if there is something I need to add to help explain the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is "Part A in the function multiple times"? Are your IF statements repeating the Part A code?

Comment: Correct, Part A is only in there multiple times because it is in each IF statement.

Comment: I am really unsure of what you are asking. If the code is working your question really belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: Yes, I can make it work with 4 IF statements, but was looking for suggestions on a more compact/elegant way of building the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function.apply` in this situation. You can store the arguments in an array, and only append to this array in the IF statements. At the end, you can invoke it by using: `someFunction.apply(this, argumentArray)`